# Neo4jPHP data storing

Tags: symfony, neo4jphp

I am new to neo4j, and i want to integrate neo4j in  my symfony php application.But iam a little bit confused here.For host iam using GrapheneDB [GrapheneDB](http://www.graphenedb.com).I did insert a couple of nodes.My question is, if i want to log requests into db, add new users, store some data, how will i distinct them, for example get users, since there is no actual "table".In doctrine i would normaly have Request, User, Data entity, and here iam just able to make node.Iam confused with this concept, documentation isnt a very helpfull, so can anybody just explain me little bit about this.Btw, iam using Neo4jPHP library

```
enter  code here
```

Answer (score 1):

On Neo4j versions > 2.0.0 you can use [labels](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/graphdb-neo4j-labels.html) to *categorize* nodes. Examples: *User*, *Company*, ...

Labels are supported in Neo4jphp: https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/wiki/Labels